# xtext nested {} Decision can match input such as "'}'" using multiple alternatives

Tags: nested, grammar, antlr3, xtext

I am new to xtext (antlr), and don't understand why there is ambiguity between IconType '}' and WindowType '}'.
I get the

```
warning(200): ../org.simsulla.tools.ui.gui/src-gen/org/simsulla/tools/ui/gui/parser/antlr/internal/InternalGui.g:137:1: Decision can match input such as "'windowType'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.simsulla.tools.ui.gui.ui/src-gen/org/simsulla/tools/ui/gui/ui/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalGui.g:117:38: Decision can match input such as "'windowType' '=' '{' 'name' '=' RULE_ID 'iconType' '=' '{' 'name' '=' RULE_ID 'spriteType' '=' RULE_STRING 'Orientation' '=' RULE_STRING '}' '}'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

This is my grammar

```
Ui:
    guiTypes+=GuiTypes+;

GuiTypes:
    windowType+=WindowType+
;

WindowType:
    'windowType' '=' '{'
        'name' '=' name=STRING
        iconType+=IconType* 
    '}'
;

IconType:
    'iconType' '=' '{'
        'name' '=' name=STRING
        'spriteType' '=' spriteType=STRING
        'Orientation' '=' Orientation=STRING
    '}'
;
```

Comment: Do you generate the debug ANTLR grammar and have you inspected it using ANTLRWorks? This tool visualizes whether there are several paths through the grammar in case of an ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar fragment has multiple ways of repeating `WindowType`:

- deriving from `Ui` to `GuiTypes` to multiple `WindowType` instances, or
- deriving from `Ui` to multiple `GuiTypes` instances where each derives to a `WindowType`, or
- any combination of the above.

So a given input corresponds to multiple different parse trees. The grammar is thus ambiguous.